# Using a search feature in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the search feature in AngularJS (in Ionic framework). I have a template consisting of different views and a common header for all views. On each view, a different list appears using JSON. I want to use the search feature for each view.

```
 <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
 </form>

<ion-item class="item-button-right item-avatar item-icon-right item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="text in texts|filter:search" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/otherContent/texts/{{text.id}}">
```

This code works fine if I use the above search `form` and `ion-item` in one single view. But does not work if I add search form in searchbar and put `<ion-item>` tag in the different page.

I hope this makes sense? Can anyone please suggest how can we implement this. I need searchbar in the header which is common for all views and it should search for each view when it is loaded. Any pointers are truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top level controller which is added to like `html` or `body` tag (if not then define a top level controller like `GlobalController` and add it to your `<html>` or `<body>` tag so that we can keep the global data there and it's scope can be globally accessible app-wide. Basically we are trying to avoid the `$rootScope` usage and mimicking the `$rootScope` usage.), then define an empty object in that global controller:

```
 $scope.globalModel = {};
```

Then, change your `ng-model` like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="globalModel.search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

And finally modify your search filter like:

```
<ion-item class="item-button-right item-avatar item-icon-right item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="text in texts|filter:globalModel.search" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/otherContent/texts/{{text.id}}">
```

The above should work. What we are doing here is that defining an object in a parent scope so that we can prevent the problem of [Angular Scopes Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Thanks alot! Working great! :)